# Kindle fire HD shows my app in portrait when i am requiring landscape

Tags: java, android

I have an app that runs in landscape mode.  It's supposed to always be in landscape mode, but if I start it on my Kindle Fire HD holding it vertically, the app will briefly try to display in portrait mode.  This causes much grief.  This brief portrait behavior doesn't happen on my phone or on the Kindle fire HD emulator.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

My manifest file has:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:name=".MyActivity">
    </activity>
```

Is there more I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, my only solution I can find is to use a workaround:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    synchronized (holder) {
        Log.view("Surface changed event: width = " + width + ", height = " + height);
        if (width < height) {
            Log.view("HEY THIS IS NOT LANDSCAPE!!!!");
            return;
        }
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

From my experience, every time the kindle fires up my 'landscape' app with a width smaller than the height (thus, by definition, not really giving me a landscape view), I just ignore the surface and wait, it quickly gives me a a real landscape (flipping the height and width so that its a true landscape view).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same defective issue of orientation with a Samsung tablet and solved it by

Settings > Display > Horizontal Calibration and;

Tap `Calibrate` after keeping the device on a flat surface. Try it and it might solve this problem.

**Important :**  This setting has been added to android after Android Version 2.3 (Ginger-Bread)

Comment: This isn't a calibration issue.  My view's surfaceChanged function is  getting called with a width that is smaller than the height.  This should never happen if my app is forcing landscape screenOrientation.

Comment: I can't find any way to calibrate a Kindle fire HD.  Besides, I don't want to receive crash reports because people have un-calibrated devices.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/152873-Kindle-Fire-HD-Auto-Rotation) says about the issue. And take into consideration of changing the orientation modes inverted only for this device. Thank you.